# How to restore accidentally removed Launcher icon for external drive in Unity?

Tags: unity, launcher, drive, portable

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit: I used to get an icon for my portable drive on insertion. I have accidentally lost this by clicking on 'Unlock from Launcher' instead of 'Eject'. Now this icon does not appear when the drive is connected. How do I restore the original behaviour?

Comment: @Pilot6 WOW, I am impressed by the gesture. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You solved my problem with a perfectly written answer. I tried to recall where this setting was stored and immediately found this Q&A.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### 1. Command line:

You can do that by the command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist "[]"
```

*Explanation*

By removing the icon from the launcher, you *blacklisted* the device from the launcher. With the command above, you "empty" the blacklist.

If you want to to have a more selective way to set which device to keep in the launcher, first run:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist
```

The output will be like:

```
['<device_1>', '<device_2>']
```

To restore `device_1` in the launcher:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist "['<device_2>']"
```

#### 2. GUI

Alternatively, you can restore your icons with `dconf-editor`. You might have to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

(Or simply install it via Software-Center)

Then open the editor, browse to: com > canonical > unity > devices:

[image]

Then you can either set the blacklist to "default" settings (which is *none*), or remove devices from the blacklist selectively.

Comment: it worked. Sorry did not come here earlier to mark acceptance.